Arcade labels not drawing in ArcGIS Online
I have a hosted feature service view that I would like to customize a label expression for.
I want to concatenate an abbreviation of one field with another field. I'm doing this in the Visualization tab for the Hosted Feature Service View. This same expression works fine in Pro 3.1, and when I run it in the AGOL console it returns the right results. It just doesn't draw the labels in the map viewer. I know that there is some issue with support for Arcade in Map Viewer Classic but I know that I am using plain old (new) Map Viewer...
Here is the expression:
var newname = dictionary(
'Brushback', 'BB',
'Chill Factor', 'CF',
'Farm Team', 'FT',
'Linebacker', 'LB',
'Log Rolling', 'LR',
'Power Play', 'PP',
'Shotgun Formation', 'SF',
'Snap Count', 'SC'
)

return newname[$feature.SaleName] + ' ' + $feature.Unit_NEPA


I used the following code and it concatenated CF to what the field creator had in it. So this worked as expected.
var newname = dictionary(
'Brushback', 'BB',
'Chill Factor', 'CF',
'Farm Team', 'FT',
'Linebacker', 'LB',
'Log Rolling', 'LR',
'Power Play', 'PP',
'Shotgun Formation', 'SF',
'Snap Count', 'SC'
);
return Concatenate(newname['Chill Factor'],' ',$feature["Creator"]);

